# Google Data Studio filter by email and allow all access

Tags: acl, looker-studio

I'm creating a Google Data Studio dashboard with the filter by email option. It's easy to do it when you want to allow the user to see only one option, for example

```
user       region
alice      A
bob        F
charlie    Z
```

But how can I do to give access to some user to all regions from A to Z? Is there a better way to do it than simply creating 26 rows for every user with this admin access?

I'd like to avoid creating this table:

```
user    region
admin   A
admin   B
admin   C
...
admin   Z
```

and instead do something similar to this

```
user    region
admin   *
```

Answer (score 0):

In bigquery connector, you can write custom query like -

select *
FROM `table_name`
where
case when @DS_USER_EMAIL IN (select distinct map_field from `table_name` )
then @DS_USER_EMAIL
else 'all' end = map_field

You will have to create a mapping for 'all' one time. But this works. No need to use feature - filter by email id